# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 UserManager alongside with UnitOfWork and Service-Locator anti-pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I was wondering whether it is a good aproach to have Identity 2.0 `UserManager` next to `UnitOfWork` pattern? I am using `UserManager` only in login and register as it gives freedom of not taking care of password hashing (also provides options to email user etc.) and user-to-role management. Although for the rest of the project I am using `UOW` to maintain users and roles (e.g. to edit user information (not password).

These are my `Login` and `Register`methods:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult >Login(UserLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    var user = (await this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.Find(u =>
        u.UserName == model.Login || u.UstId == model.Login)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user == null)
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("Login", Properties.Error.UserDoesntExist);
        return this.View();
    }
    var userManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<LeaveUserManager>();
    var authManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

    if (!await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("Password", Properties.Error.WrongPassword);
        return this.View();
    }

    var ident = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

    this.TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Logged in";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(UserRegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View();
    }
    var userManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<LeaveUserManager>();

    var user = new User(model);
    var result = userManager.Create(user, model.Password);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        result.Errors.ForEach(e => this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e));
        return this.View();
    }

    var userRole = this.unitOfWork.UserRoleRepository.Find(ur => ur.Name == "User").Result.FirstOrDefault();
    if (userRole == null)
    {
        userRole = new UserRole("User");

        this.unitOfWork.UserRoleRepository.Add(userRole);
        this.unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");

    this.TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Registered";
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And assigning user to role also uses `UserManager`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Assign(AssignRoleViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }
    var userManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<LeaveUserManager>();

    userManager.RemoveFromRoles(model.Id, userManager.GetRoles(model.Id).ToArray());
    if (model.SelectedRoles.Any())
    {
        userManager.AddToRoles(model.Id, model.SelectedRoles.ToArray());
    }
    return this.RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.Id });
}
```

Although Edit method uses `uow`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(User model)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(model.Id);
        user.EditUser(model);
        await this.unitOfWork.Complete();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    var userList = this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll().Result;
    this.ViewBag.SuperiorId = new SelectList(userList, "Id", "FirstName", model.SuperiorId);
    return this.View(model);
}
```

And my `UserManager`:

```
public class LeaveUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public LeaveUserManager(IUserStore<User> store) : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static LeaveUserManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<LeaveUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new LeaveUserManager(
            new UserStore<User>(context.Get<VacationsContext>()))
        {
            EmailService = new LeaveEmailService()
        };
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Is it OK to leave it like this or I should create my own userManager which will be using uow and repositories?
I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with EF6.

---

2018-03-20 edit:
I have removed `.Result` from all async methods and replaced with `await`.
I have dependency injected all `managers`, `dbcontext` and `uow` using `Ninject` library.

```
    private static void RegisterService(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<VacationsContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<RoleManager<UserRole>>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<LeaveUserManager>().ToMethod(c => LeaveUserManager.Create(kernel.Get<VacationsContext>())).InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserStore<User>>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<VacationsContext>());
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

Injection works in controllers:

```
public HomeController(LeaveUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authManager, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    this.leaveUserManager = userManager;
    this.authenticationManager = authManager;
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

And if noone says that it is some kind of violation - then I will leave `LeaveUserManager` as it is - using it's own way to database access layer (skipping my custom uow).

Comment: `UserManager` is more of an implementation concern that you can encapsulate behind your own abstraction in whatever structure/pattern you want.

Comment: Avoid `.Result` within async methods as those blocking calls can lead to deadlocks

Comment: you should post edits to your code as a new question(review request) so that you can get more feedback.

Comment: @Malachi, I think that this is now pretty clear for me, but maybe it would be a good idea to modify question title that this also references to DI and Service Locator anti-pattern. Morelike for others than for me, what do you think?

Comment: Oh, I see you didn't actually show the changes you made just added other code pertinent to the review.  You did good. As you were...lol

Comment: Then we are good, I have modified title of question to be more precise about nature of the review. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid `.Result` within async methods

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(User model) {
    //...

    var userList = this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll().Result;

    //...
}
```

as those blocking calls can lead to deadlocks. Make the function async all the way through

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(User model) {
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid) {
        var user = await this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(model.Id);
        user.EditUser(model);
        await this.unitOfWork.Complete();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    var userList = await this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll();
    this.ViewBag.SuperiorId = new SelectList(userList, "Id", "FirstName", model.SuperiorId);
    return this.View(model);
}
```

Next, it appears that DI and service locator is being mixed.

```
var userManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<LeaveUserManager>();
var authManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

could be seen as a service locator anti-pattern within the action being called.

Assuming the `unitOfWork` is being injected into the controller then user manager and authentication should be explicitly injected as well.

> Is it ok to leave it like this or I should create my own userManager which will be using uow and repositories?

Entity Framework is already built following the UOW/Repository pattern and Identity Framework is built on top of it.

`UserManager` and by extension Identity Framework is more of an implementation concern/detail that you can encapsulate behind your own abstraction in whatever structure/pattern you want.

Instead of focusing on that pattern consider just creating a service to perform the desired functionality and inject that into your dependent classes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out using `.Result` in async methods. I have fixed this in all project :). If I understood correctly - It would be good for me to create a service that would take some of the functionality (that I need) from userManager and would use my UoW? I know that EF is based on UoW and Repos, but in this case I have my custom UoW and user Manager is not using my custom uow.

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki That works perfectly, and saves you from having to build your own service. My only issue is that classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions. While injecting the class in you scenario works, it is not a very good design.

Comment: do you mean like I should use `UserManager` instead of `LeaveUserManager`, or you mean something else?

Comment: Not necessarily. An interface would be as abstract as you can get, but like I said before, what you have can work.

Comment: In case of `UserManager` there is no interface, but I could still use it, because it is still more abstract than `LeaveUserManager`. I am pretty new to Dependency Injection in practice, so I just want to understand how things should work in live project

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki I understand that. `UserManager` is a poor example because of how it was designed. I do believe you understand the principle behind the practice though.

Comment: I think I do understand. That is why I have changed for example `UnitOfWork` to `IUnitOfWork` in all controllers - to be dependent on abstraction and be able to mock it anytime soon. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki glad to help